# Accessing routes on different server from within a server (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I have three express servers `app1`, `app2`, and `app3` running on different ports. All servers have a route `/api/example`, but only `app1` is connected to a UI, and I want whenever I hit the route `/api/example` in app1 from the frontend, to forward the request to the same route in `app2` **and** `app3` from within the the route in `app1`, and once the data returned from the the other two routes, to combine them in `app1` and send them back to the UI. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make requests to your other two servers, wait for the results to come back from both and then process those two results into your final result:

```
const got = require('got');

const port2 = somePort2;    // port for app2
const port3 = somePort3;    // port for app3    

app1.get("/api/:command", (req, res) => {
    Promise.all([
        got(`http://localhost:${port2}/api/${req.params.command}`).json(),
        got(`http://localhost:${port3}/api/${req.params.command}`).json(),
    ]).then(([r2, r3]) => {
        // process r2 and r3 to combine them
        res.send(...);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Note, this assumes you're getting JSON back from app2 and app3.  If it's a different type of data, then adjust the `.json()` to match the type of data you're getting back.